# Android WebView ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to allow user to login into our application through a WebView, but when trying to login, I get an error saying `ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS`. The login protocol consists of 5 redirects, but we have no control over it.

It works in a web browser, but Anroid WebView starts thinking we are in a redirect loop and cancels the whole thing. Up until API 8 there was a function `onTooManyRedirects(WebView view, Message cancelMsg, Message continueMsg)`, which allowed you to continue, but is now not used anymore.

What can I do to get around this problem?

Answer (score 3):

In my code I have the following line:

```
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
```

Just deleting this line solve the issue.

Comment: why is this solution working?. I'm looking for other solutions as this solution may result in unexpected behaviors.